# Delete unusable characters or data in archive with python

Tags: python

I have an archive with unusable data and I want to clean them with python.

First, the lines have the form:

```
Xac:0.01660156#,Yac:0.02343750?,Zac:1.00683593*
```

I want to delete: `Xac:`, `Yac:`, and `Zac:`, and also the characters at the ends of number like `#`, `?`, `*` to leave only numbers.

Also, I want to delete some trash lines in the archive like:

```
!Data Logger Accelerometer] , 

Initializing...
```

Lines like those in the archive are trash for me and I need to delete them to leave a clean archive with only numbers on three columns. (Really, those numbers are accelerometer readings on the `x`, `y`, and `z` axes, but I have unusable data like I showed above).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How far have your own efforts gotten you and where, precisely, are you having trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the data file.

First, skip invalid lines:

```
if not line.startswith('Xac:'):
    return None
```

Second, split by non-number chars:

```
parts = re.split('[,Xac:YZ#?*]', line)
```

Third, filter empty strs:

```
parts = filter(lambda x: bool(x), parts)
```

Fourth, covert `str` to `float`:

```
parts = map(lambda x: float(x), parts)
```

Finally, convert `list` to `tuple`

```
return tuple(parts)
```

The full example is like this:

```
import re


def parse_line(line):
    """ line -> (int, int, int), None if invalid
    """
    if not line.startswith('Xac:'):
        return None
    parts = re.split('[,Xac:YZ#?*]', line)
    parts = filter(lambda x: bool(x), parts)
    parts = map(lambda x: float(x), parts)
    return tuple(parts)

output = []
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in iter(f.readline, ''):
        axes = parse_line(line.strip())
        if axes:
            output.append(axes)
print output
```

Input file `input.txt`:

```
!Data Logger Accelerometer] ,

Initializing...

Xac:0.01660156#,Yac:0.02343750?,Zac:1.00683593*
```

OUTPUT:

```
[(0.01660156, 0.0234375, 1.00683593)]
```

Comment: Many Thanks!!!, i exactly that i need, work perfectly!! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use python regular expressions.

```
import re 
x = 'Xac:0.01660156#,Yac:0.02343750?,Zac:1.00683593*'
print re.findall('(\d*\.?\d+)', x)  #['0.01660156', '0.02343750', '1.00683593']
```